# Substitute fn for CWnd::SubclassCtl3d() that is supported in Visual Studio 2017's MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

I'm porting an MFC application from VC6 (MFC42.dll) to Visual Studio 2017. Everything else built just fine except the calls to the fn CWnd::SubclassCtl3d(). I googled to get this fn's documentation but could not get anything useful.

With which API/member fn in VS2017's MFC I can replace the calls to this fn?

The descriptive comment about this calls says this:

```
// Since this window is really an edit control but does not
// have "edit" as its class name, to make it work correctly
// with CTL3D, we have to tell CTL3D that is "really is" an
// edit control. This uses a relatively new API in CTL3D
// called Ctl3dSubclassCtlEx.
```

and then the call is made like so:

```
pEdit->SubclassCtl3d(CTL3D_EDIT_CTL);
```

pEdit is a pointer to a CEdit object (and CEdit derives from CWnd).

Comment: Have a read of: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/54047f54-f276-4c7d-9b67-6689ffeff4c8/migrating-a-vc6-application-using-ctl3dh?forum=vcmfcatl

Comment: @RichardCritten The link talks about Ctl3dSubclassCtl() while  my query is about a different fn -  CWnd::SubclassCtl3d(). So, it is not useful.

Comment: The point is the whole of `ctl3d` is gone (3D controls for Windows 95).  The control styles have been moved into the core windows controls.

Comment: @RichardCritten so that means I can safely remove this call???

Comment: Depends what is the code doing with the control after it has been subclassed?

Comment: You can probably remove all ctl3d related stuff alltogether, this is deprecated stuff since at least 20 years.